# Widget that acts like an Excel cell (can input a formula, displayed text is result of formula)?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to create a widget (text field or other) where on clicking on it I can enter some text, but the displayed value is something else. Similar to an Excel cell with a formula: you can edit the formula, but you see the result.

Is that possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible. In the example below a TextField currently changes some text to uppercase when the editing is completed. When the TextField is tapped it returns to showing the original input. You should be able to modify this to what you need.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExcelFormulaField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExcelFormulaFieldState createState() => _ExcelFormulaFieldState();
}

class _ExcelFormulaFieldState extends State<ExcelFormulaField> {
  String input;
  String output;
  bool isInputActive;
  TextEditingController controller;

  void updateInput(text) => setState(() {
        input = text;
      });

  void setInputActive() => setState(() {
        if (isInputActive != true) {
          isInputActive = true;

          resetController();

          print("Active");
          print("Input: $input, Output: $output");
        }
      });

  void setInputInactive() => setState(() {
        isInputActive = false;

        // TODO replace with the logic you want
        output = input.toUpperCase();
        controller = TextEditingController(text: output);

        print("InActive");
        print("Input: $input, Output: $output");
      });

  void resetController() {
    controller = TextEditingController(text: input);
    controller.addListener(() => updateInput(controller.text));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isInputActive = false;
    resetController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setInputInactive();
      },
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "input",
                  labelText: "Hit enter on keyboard to see change"),
              onTap: () {
                setInputActive();
              },
              onEditingComplete: () {
                setInputInactive();
              },
              controller: controller,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I am trying to implement it. I was using a TextFormField initially, but I think I managed to adapt my code to the TextField.

However, now I am running into some issues.

I am trying to use the textformfields in a gridview. I change the value in a cell, I put "5 + 5" for example, it displays "10", so that's correct. But when I scroll and the cell is no longer visible, when I scroll back, the cell value has been reset. 

Not sure if I should edit my initial post or make another one.

Comment: Is the cell reset like it shows "5 + 5" or is it empty? Does specifying a UniqueKey() in the key field  of the cells help?

Comment: Cells are initialized with 0. After I put 5+5 and 10 is displayed, after I scroll down and back up, value is 0 again.

I will try to post a video of it.

Comment: Maybe this will work: What if you add some parameters in the constructor of the custom TextField widget you have, where you specifying the input and output of the widget. In addition add a "final Function(String, String, int) textFieldValues;" which you call when the values is updated. The strings is input & output, "int" is for the index. Store these values in a data structure in the widget containing the GridView which then repopulates it with the previous values.  Not sure this will work, but it is a suggestion :-)