# Flutter: Adding a hyphen and brackets to a user's phone number entered in a textfield

Tags: flutter

I am trying to rearrange a user's entered phone number with brackets around the area code and a hyphen. For example, the user would enter 9991234567 and it would be rearranged to (999) 123-4567 inside the textfield.

I'm using a RegExp to separate the user's entry into the area code, and the 2 parts of the phone number. I am attempting to use a TextEditingController to edit the text field with brackets and a hyphen when the Save button is pressed but it does not seem to work.

```
_saveButtonPressed() async {
    RegExp phone = RegExp(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})');
    var matches = phone.allMatches(UserProfile.instance.phone);
    var match = matches.elementAt(0);
    setState(() {
      phoneController.text = '(${match.group(1)}) ${match.group(2)}-${match.group(3)}';
    });
  }
```

This is the code for the phone number textfield.

```
  _makeRowForAttribute(
            imageAsset: "assets/images/phone.png",
            title: "PHONE NUMBER",
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            placeholder: "6131110123",
            charLimit: 10,
            initialValue: UserProfile.instance.phone,
            controller: phoneController,
            onSave: (phone) {
              UserProfile.instance.phone = phone.toString();
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Your RegExp seem to be working when tested with a hardcoded string.  You could take a look at this question I answered earlier today which might have some relevance for your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811087/widget-that-acts-like-an-excel-cell-can-input-a-formula-displayed-text-is-resu/55816304#55816304

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it appears that my RegExp is working. However, I think there is a problem with my use of the controller.

Comment: Try to use InputFormatter: `TextField(inputFormatters: [
            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})')),
          ])  `

Comment: Where do you suggest I try the InputFormatter sorry? Where I have setState?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [flutter_masked_text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_masked_text#maskedtext) package

It's just simple as following

```dart
import 'package:flutter_masked_text/flutter_masked_text.dart';

class MobileNumberTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => MobileNumberTextFieldState();
}

class MobileNumberTextFieldState extends State<MobileNumberTextField> {

  final controller =MaskedTextController(mask: "(000) 000-0000");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      autofocus: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FormattedPhoneNumber extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormattedPhoneNumberState createState() => _FormattedPhoneNumberState();
}

class _FormattedPhoneNumberState extends State<FormattedPhoneNumber> {
  String text = "";

  convert(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    print("OldValue: ${oldValue.text}, NewValue: ${newValue.text}");
    String newText = newValue.text;

    if (newText.length == 10) {
      // The below code gives a range error if not 10.
      RegExp phone = RegExp(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})');
      var matches = phone.allMatches(newValue.text);
      var match = matches.elementAt(0);
      newText = '(${match.group(1)}) ${match.group(2)}-${match.group(3)}';
    }

    // TODO limit text to the length of a formatted phone number?

    setState(() {
      text = newText;
    });

    return TextEditingValue(
        text: newText,
        selection: TextSelection(
            baseOffset: newValue.text.length,
            extentOffset: newValue.text.length));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextField(
            inputFormatters: [
              TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
                  (oldValue, newValue) => convert(oldValue, newValue)),
            ],
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: "input",
                labelText: "Converts to phone number format"),

            // Fixes a problem with text-caret only being at the start of the textfield.
            controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(new TextEditingValue(
                text: text,
                selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: text.length))),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not detecting any change to the user's entered number when I tried to integrate this code into mine.